# Android/ Java - Zooming in on my drawn canvas

Tags: java, android, camera, zooming, maze

I have created a 2D maze which consists of 2 sets of boolean array, refering to the verticle and horizontal walls for my maze. This maze is currently 12 x 12, however I only ever want to show 5 x 5.

Is there a way to zoom the maze to a 5 x 5 circumfrance of where the user is and then simply show the next block every time they move, therefore only ever showing 5 x 5.

Ideally I want to stick to drawing the whole thing out and then simply having some sort of birdseye view zoom (this will improve usability and generally speed up the app).

*EDIT*
Below is the code I am currently using in order to draw the maze. However, the below code does not seem to be drawing the correct v and hLines as I move the user circle.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, background);
    mazeSizeX = 5 + maze.getCurrentX();
    mazeSizeY = 5 + maze.getCurrentY();
    for(int i = maze.getCurrentX(); i < mazeSizeX; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = maze.getCurrentY(); j < mazeSizeY; j++){
            float x = j * totalCellWidth;
            float y = i * totalCellHeight;
            if(j < mazeSizeX -1 && vLines[i][j]) {
                //we'll draw a vertical line
                canvas.drawLine(x + cellWidth,   //start X
                                y,               //start Y
                                x + cellWidth,   //stop X
                                y + cellHeight,  //stop Y
                                line);
            }
            if(i < mazeSizeY -1 && hLines[i][j]) {
            //we'll draw a horizontal line
                canvas.drawLine(x,               //startX 
                                y + cellHeight,  //startY 
                                x + cellWidth,   //stopX 
                                y + cellHeight,  //stopY 
                                line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE - mazeSizeX and Y are intially set on 5. Any further guidenece as to where i am going wrong would be much appreciated.

EDIT 2:
Please see the below image to indicate 3 different steps a user may have taken to help further explain the issue I am having. The first image is the starting point and has been drawn as it should, however when I started moving the user circle around the lines are not drawn correctly.

[image: 3 differnt user position showing drawLine issue]

Finally, please see below the current boolean array I am using in order to draw the waze walls:

```
boolean[][] vLines = new boolean[][]{
                        {true ,false,false,false,true ,false,false},
                        {true ,false,false,true ,false,true ,true },
                        {false,true ,false,false,true ,false,false},
                        {false,true ,true ,false,false,false,true },
                        {true ,false,false,false,true ,true ,false},
                        {false,true ,false,false,true ,false,false},
                        {false,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,false},
                        {false,false,false,true ,false,false,false}
                     };
boolean[][] hLines = new boolean[][]{
                        {false,false,true ,true ,false,false,true ,false},
                        {false,false,true ,true ,false,true ,false,false},
                        {true ,true ,false,true ,true ,false,true ,true },
                        {false,false,true ,false,true ,true ,false,false},
                        {false,true ,true ,true ,true ,false,true ,true },
                        {true ,false,false,true ,false,false,true ,false},
                        {false,true ,false,false,false,true ,false,true }
                    };
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's quite hard to answer this without knowing more about how you're doing it today..

Comment: I essentially have an array of boolean e.g. true, true, false etc, the true will draw a solid line false nothing. These will be used as the wall maze. Then I trigger an onDraw to create the whole maze at once, then there are 2 further points which are drawn, 1 for the starting position defined with cordinaltion (x,y) and the same for the finsih point. I hope the above is clear, if there is something specific please let me know and i will try to be more spefic. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use two variables, `scroll_x` and `scroll_y` that you use when drawing and modify when moving, so that your maze always is drawn as 5 x 5 and you use the two variables to determine the offset of which parts of the map you should draw.

Also, you could implement `zoom_x` and `zoom_y` variables to change the zooming if you'd like.

Since you're using the onDraw method, that excludes any possibilities I can think of of "paint everything once and moving the map around".

This is the best answer I can give at the moment, based on your description of the problem.

**EDIT:**

Now that you have provided more information, here's a redesigned onDraw for you:

In the function below, I have used `maze.scrollX` and `maze.scrollY` to work as the scroll-offset if the maze is larger than 5 x 5. I've also added `drawSize` properties to define how big the are you want to draw should be. If you're in the upper-left part of the map, both of these should be set to zero. I haven't tested this code myself so please inform me about how it works.

Please note that this code has no error check, if `maze.scrollX` is too big, then it will cause an error.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, background);
    int drawSizeX = 5;
    int drawSizeY = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < drawSizeX - 1; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < drawSizeY - 1; j++){
            float x = j * totalCellWidth;
            float y = i * totalCellHeight;
            if(vLines[i + maze.scrollX][j + maze.scrollY]) {
                //we'll draw a vertical line
                canvas.drawLine(x + cellWidth,   //start X
                                y,               //start Y
                                x + cellWidth,   //stop X
                                y + cellHeight,  //stop Y
                                line);
            }
            if(hLines[i + maze.scrollX][j + maze.scrollY]) {
            //we'll draw a horizontal line
                canvas.drawLine(x,               //startX 
                                y + cellHeight,  //startY 
                                x + cellWidth,   //stopX 
                                y + cellHeight,  //stopY 
                                line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will be looking at this over the next couple of days (as busy at work at the moment) and will let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: Good luck, I can try to help you more if you provide more information (the code for how you're doing the drawing for example). But it's also good if you try it for yourself :)

Comment: I am creating the maze in a similar way as to your answer, which is drawing the zoom correctly. However, when I move my cursor it is not drawing the new lines for some reason, please see my edited question with a code snipped of how i am drawing the maze. Thanks

Comment: Check your values for mazeSizeX, mazeSizeY (I'm not sure why you're modifying those in the onDraw function?), width, height, and also make sure that you're not attempting to draw outside the view.

Comment: I have changed my MazeSizeX/Y slightly, the reason I am using these as I would like to keep chaging the starting and ending point for the boolean array in order to draw the new lines as the user moves. However, currently when I move the user down from co-ordinates (0,0) to (0,1), loads of lines are not drawn correctly. But if i move back to (0,0) they are, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @weebo123 I would not use `mazeSizeX = mazeSizeX + maze.getCurrentX();` but rather do `mazeSizeX = maze.getCurrentX();`

Comment: I am no longer using mazeSizeX = mazeSizeX + maze.getCurrentX(); please see edited code with my orginal question. I am using 5 as this is the indication to draw only 5 lines from the boolean array which I am using to create the maze. I am essentially trying to re-draw the map everytime the user moves using the current cordination as the starting point for the map. Thanks

Comment: Hi Simon, please see my edited question I have added the screen shot you requested (3 different user position, the first one drawing correctly). I have also, added the boolean array I am using in order to draw the maze walls. Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem better now. Look at my edited answer and check how that code works for you.

Comment: Hi, not quite sure what you are defining for the maze.ScrollX within the vLines[i + maze.scrollX][j + maze.scrollY]. Sorry im a new to Java and get thrown by the odd terminology. Am i right in thinking ScrollX acts in the same way as getCurrentX() - which returns the current co-ordinates?

Comment: I never defined scrollX and scrollY. I thought about these as properties for the maze (you can add these properties yourself). And no, scrollX does not act the same way as getCurrentX. getCurrentX will give you the position of the circle. scrollX is meant for the difference between the top-left that you see and the top-left that actually exists in the maze. How big do you want your maze to be? vLines is currently 7 x 8 in size while hLines is 8 x 7, that's a little confusing for me.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the use of ScrollX and ScrollY. As for the maze it is currently 7x7, the v&hLines are slightly different due to where they are placed on the map (as require top and bottom which is not relly visible at all time). Once this is complete the maze will actrually be significatly bigger at 100x100+. Unfortunetly, I have not been able to get your above code to work, I will continue trying and will accept your answer if I can get your implemention to work. Thanks

Comment: yes have made some progress, but still getting a few issue. Got it building as it should everytime I move. However, currently it breaks when you get a certain distance into the array. Once I have this working the final thing i need to work out is placing the user in the middle and building the maze around the user circle (user circle should always be in the middle with 3 places surrounding it)

Comment: Hi I have worked out how to get the map to draw as it should and got it working so that the use circlet is always in the middle. However, I am having a few issues with the validation of the array as currently when i progress a certain distance into the maze the app crashes (I assume this is due to coming to the end of the array). Any help here?

Comment: @LandLPartners I think you should start a new question on StackOverflow for that.

Comment: Ok will do, thanks for your help and I will accept your answer.